# caching configured still some images are having different cache time on magneto

Tags: nginx, cache

I am running a magneto on nginx and I have configured the images caching for a year still in gtmetrix for some of the images I get caching (5 minutes)

```
        server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 default_server ssl;

    server_name somedomain.com;
    server_name www.somedomain.com;
    server_name ipv4.somedomain.com;
    pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
    pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;

    ssl_certificate             /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-TANhO4;
    ssl_certificate_key         /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-TANhO4;
    ssl_client_certificate      /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-R31hv6;
    ssl_session_timeout         5m;

    ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/somedomain/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/somedomain/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/somedomain/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://192.168.1.232:7081;
            proxy_set_header Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
            access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/somedomain/httpdocs/;
            add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
            internal;
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=30d,public";
            expires 30d;
     }

    # Images
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|zip|woff)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=1y";
            expires 1y;
    }
```

}

example: http://somesite/images/siteimages/category_tiles_109x109/xgold-hollow-cross-tile.gif.pagespeed.ic.EbboFWD5Wz.png (5 minutes)

Comment: Posting an actual URL, ideally direct to the server, would be useful. Alternately "curl -i" (showing headings) for both hitting the magneto directly (if possible) and hitting Nginx.

Comment: I'll just add in here the result of the gtmetrix: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.joyjewelers.com/CzDiXF1j

Comment: Browsing the individual images does show that they are cached but not when I browse the main domain.

Comment: The information Tim asked is still required to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you haven't compiled headers_more into Nginx. To confirm whether or not you have add this in your image location block

```
add_header XYZ "TESTING";
```

Post the output of "curl -i", or you can see the headers with Firefox and the "Live HTTP Headers" plugin. Also, drop the "pragma", it's old and unnecessary. Basically, copy my block below, at least the parts you need.

If you want instructions on how to build Nginx with headers_mode see my tutorial [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source).

For reference here's my own location blog that does something similar

```
# Cache images on the client. Don't log errors or access. Block hotlinking.
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
  log_not_found off; access_log off;

  valid_referers none blocked server_names ~($host) ~(googleusercontent|google|bing|yahoo);
  if ($invalid_referer) {
    rewrite (.*) /stop-stealing-images.png redirect;
    # drop the 'redirect' flag for redirect without URL change (internal rewrite)
  }

  # Set up caching - 8 days for static resources. Remove the old unnecessary Pragma and hide the server version
  more_clear_headers "Cache-Control";
  add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
  more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers "Expires";

  # add_header Z_LOCATION "wpmu STATIC RESOURCES REGEX"; add_header URI $uri; # Nginx Debugging
}
```

Comment: Browing the image directly does have hte proper headers configured: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 4934
Connection: keep-alive
Link: <http://www.joyjewelers.com/images/siteimages/category_tiles_109x109/gold-hollow-cross-tile.gif>; rel="canonical"
Server: nginx
Pragma: public
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2016 01:27:03 GMT
Expires: Sun, 08 Oct 2017 01:27:03 GMT
ETag: W/"0"
Last-Modified: Sat, 08 Oct 2016 01:27:03 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
X-Page-Speed: 1.11.33.4-0

Comment: I see what you mean. Try turning off PageSpeed for a bit, and re-run the test. I also note that with this test some of the png requests are returning images of type image/gif, but that could be a problem with the testing system, as in Firefox they look ok https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161008_79_ceed0c8d66568fbe641e97330e9b9feb/

Comment: I have temporarly disabled the PageSpeed and then everything working as it should. Therefore the problem is that the PageSpeed module is regenerating the file and it's renaming for example from mid_row_gold_crosses.jpeg to xmid_row_gold_crosses.jpeg.pagespeed.ic.WvXRgmg4WN.jpg. and the second file name does not match the regex of the nginx configuration. Any suggestion?

Comment: I looked at PageSpeed but it gave virtually no speedup and caused some weird issue. I think the solution to your problem is to keep PageSpeed turned off.